# WP Problems with add_body_class in functions.php--class not added

Tags: wordpress

I'm using JointsWP theme and am trying to get my custom post type archive to have an additional class but it's not working.

The only body classes I get on archive_yacht_for_sale.php are:

- blog
- logged-in
- 2008-jeanneau-54ds (title of first post on
  the page)
- hyg-blog-index (one of my custom body classes. This should by hyg-yacht-index).

ALL my custom body classes are working except the one for post_type_archive. I have already tried it in the my_body_classes function, that did not work either. I also have ended the loop with

```
<?php endif; 
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

to no avail.

This is making it virtually impossible to target the custom post type archive in the css as the blog has the same body classes.

Here is the relevant code in my functions.php.

```
function add_body_class( $hygclasses ) {
global $post;
if ( isset( $post ) ) {
    $hygclasses[] = $post->post_name;
} 
return $hygclasses;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_body_class' );


function my_body_classes( $classes ) {
if (is_page(array(13,41,44))) {     
    $classes[] = 'parent-pageid-23';     
} elseif (is_home()) {
    $classes[] = 'hyg-blog-index'; 
 } elseif (is_singular('post')) {
    $classes[] = 'hyg-blog-single';  
}
return $classes;   
}
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );

function more_body_classes( $classes ) {
if (is_post_type_archive()){
     $classes[] = 'hyg-yacht-index'; 
}
return $classes;   
}
add_filter( 'body_class','more_body_classes' );`
```

The problem is definitely with the post_type_archive as I tried adding

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> <?php if (is_post_type_archive()){ ?> id="hyg-yacht-index" <?php } ?>>
```

to no avail (again).

There are no plugins controlling post types or taxonomies.

I originally posted this on Wordpress.org three weeks ago.

Comment: what is your custom post name ?

Answer (score 0):

To check if the archive page is a custom post type archive page, you should use

`is_post_type_archive('your_post_name')`

So, replace

`is_post_type_archive()`

with

`is_post_type_archive('your_post_name')`

Your function will be:

```
function my_body_classes( $classes )
{
    if (is_page(array(13,41,44)))
    {
        $classes[] = 'parent-pageid-23';
    } 
    elseif (is_home()) 
    {
        $classes[] = 'hyg-blog-index';
    } 
    elseif (is_singular('post')) 
    {
        $classes[] = 'hyg-blog-single';
    }
    elseif (is_post_type_archive('your_post_type')) 
    {
        $classes[] = 'hyg-yacht-index';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hi Sabari, Unfortunately I tried that as well, it didn't work. The custom archive is archive-yacht_for_sale.php and the custom post type is yacht_for_sale.

Comment: are you sure the page you are loading is the archive page? What is your archive page url?

Comment: Yes, because it's bringing in the loop (loop-archive-yachts.php) that's called from archive-yacht_for_sale.php as follows:

 <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'archive-yachts' ); ?>

There is content in the loop-archive-yachts.php which is not in the default archive.php.

When I delete ALL body class functions from functions.php all I get on the custom post archive are: **blog logged-in**.

It should have post-type-archive-yacht-for-sale  as well

When I look at a tag archive in the blog section, the classes in the body are: archive tag tag-yacht-management tag-47 logged-in

Comment: what is your page url for the archive page? I believe it should be http://yourdomain.com/yacht_for_sale